# storage.bucket error when i try t post image to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage

i am having issues posting an image to my firebase storage, i keep getting the error:

> Userprofile.js:62
>
> Uncaught TypeError: storage.bucket is not a function
> at handleFireBaseUpload (Userprofile.js:62:1)

the error happens when i click submit button. How do i properly set up my storage for firebase ? look at my imports of firebase

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Paper } from "@mui/material";
import authHeader from "../../features/authentication/AuthHeader";
//import {storage} from "./firebase.js";

// test
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
//import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
//import "firebase/storage" ;

import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB8vxklg6-m-",
  authDomain: ".firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "kvck",
  storageBucket: "appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "cifc",
  appId: "1::web:"
};
//initilize firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = 'dart-cart-273ad.appspot.com';
//const storage = firebase.storage();
//test

function UserProfile() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  async function fetchUser() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:9005/getProfile", {
      headers: authHeader(),
    });
    const fetchedUser = await response.json();
    console.log(fetchedUser);
    setUser(fetchedUser);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  //firebase upload
  const allInputs = { imgUrl: "" };
  const [imageAsFile, setImageAsFile] = useState("");
  const [imageAsUrl, SetImageAsUrl] = useState(allInputs);

  const handleImageAsFile = (e) => {
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    setImageAsFile((imageFile) => image);
  };

  const handleFireBaseUpload = e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('uploading pic');
    if(imageAsFile===''){
      alert(`image format not supported${typeof(imageAsFile)}`);
    }

    
    const uploadTask = storage.bucket(`/images/${imageAsFile.name}`).put(imageAsFile);
  }
 

  return (
    <>
      <paper 
      elevation={6}
      >
        <div className="pfp">
          <form onSubmit={handleFireBaseUpload}>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleImageAsFile} />
            <p>hgk</p>
            <button>test</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </paper>

      <Paper
        elevation={6}
        style={{ margin: "10px", padding: "15px", textAlign: "left" }}
        key={user.user_id}
      >
        First Name: {user.firstName}
        <br />
        Last Name: {user.lastName}
        <br />
        Email: {user.email}
        <br />
        Phone: {user.phone}
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
}
export { UserProfile as default };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase changed its syntax last year, and the new syntax is incompatible with the older one. Your code seems to be halfway between porting from the older namespaced syntax of SDK versions 8 and before, and the newer modulr syntax of SDK versions 9 and later.

Your `storage` variable is declared and initialized with:

```
const storage = 'dart-cart-273ad.appspot.com';
```

So that means it is a string value, and it doesn't have a `bucket` property.

---

You seem to want to use Cloud Storage, but you're not importing the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage anywhere in your code yet. To do that, use:

```
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

...

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
```

To learn how to get started with the new v9 SDK, I recommend studying the <kbd>Web version 9 (modular)</kbd> snippets in the Firebase documentation on [getting started with Cloud Storage in your web app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start), which is pretty much where I got this code from. If you keep reading there, you'll also find [how to upload files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) in this new, modular SDK syntax

Comment: when i do that, i get the error 'firebaseApp' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Did you read the documentation that I linked in my answer?